# How to change css when theme changes in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am developing a library of react components and asked an important question. How to correctly change styles (css) when changing the application theme. 
Appeal to those who already have experience in this and who can advise their approach or solution. 
Now I'll tell you how it works for me:


I have my own themeProvider wrapped in a Context with the ability to change the theme.
When the theme changes in the provider, the changeCssVariables method is called.

```
export const changeCssVariables = (theme) => {
    const root = document.querySelector(':root');

    // root.style.setProperty('--default-color', 'orange');

    const cssVariables = [
        'color', 
        'background',

        'color-uibutton',
        'background-uibutton',
        'box-shadow-uibutton',
        'color-disabled-uibutton',
        'background-disabled-uibutton',

        'background-uiradiobutton',

        'color-uiinputext',
        'color-notes-uiinputext',

        'color-subsection',
        'background-subsection',
        'box-shadow-subsection',
        'alt-subsection',
        'on-subsection',
        'off-subsection',

        
    ];

    cssVariables.forEach(element => {
        root.style.setProperty(
            `--default-${element}`, 
            `var(--theme-${theme}-${element})`
        );
    })
}
```

What happens in general: it has a global CSS with variables default, light and dark themes. When changing the theme, a method is called that changes the default variable to the variable of the selected theme. 
Example css:

```
--default-color: var(--theme-light-color);
/* Themes */

    --theme-light-color: #000;
    --theme-dark-color: #fff;
```

I don't like that you have to pull in all the css and change it this way. What is the solution?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using styled components ?

Comment: I did not quite understand the meaning of the question. If you are asking if I am using the npm package (styled-components), then my answer is no, and if you are asking what css is used to style a component, then yes.

Comment: Your problem can be solved if you use the npm package styled components, you can change the CSS by passing it as props.

Comment: I have already considered this approach, it does not suit me, too many props will have to be passed to the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in using styled-components package 
Created my wrapper as ThemeProvider (Context)